# PHP error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php, variables, standards, strict

Receiving this error when using PHP to create an image gallery;
"Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in (filename) on line 5"

Does anyone know how to either fix or hide this error? As the actual gallery works fine with the error. Thanks!

Below is the code:

```
public function getImages($extensions = array('jpg', 'png')) {
    $images = $this->getDirectory($this->path);

        foreach($images as $index => $image) {
            $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image)));
            if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
                unset($images[$index]);
            } else {
                $images[$index] = array(
                    'full' => $this->path . '/' . $image,
                    'thumb' => $this->path . '/thumbs/' . $image,
                    );
            }
        }

    return (count($images)) ? $images : false;
}
```

Comment: it's hard to say since there aren't even 25 lines in what you've posted, where is line 25 ?

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'm really sorry, I forgot the change the value when taking the snippet. Has been updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end()` requires an actual array because it will move the pointer to the end.

`end(explode('.', $image))` will not work.

Instead you could try for instance:

`$extension = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`